# "Out of domain" error in MathProg (GLPK)

Tags: ampl, glpk, operations-research, mathprog

I am struggling with a seemingly simple model in MathProg. The model is as follows:

```
set W;
set V;

param b {W, V} binary;
param p;

var w {j in W} <= 0, >= 1;

minimize obj: 0;

subject to within_radius_of {i in V}:
    sum {j in W} b[i,j] * w[j] >= 1;

subject to p_limit:
    sum {j in W} w[j] <= p;

end;
```

When I run it, it gives me the error `feasibility.glp:11: b[v1,w1] out of domain`. I have no idea what is going wrong. Even more strange to me, if I change the relevant line to `b[j,i]` it keeps giving the exact same error (not `b[w1,v1]` as I expected).

I inspected the [AMPL Diet Example](http://www.ampl.com/EXAMPLES/MCDONALDS/diet1.mod) carefully, and despite me seeing no difference in the relevant part of my model it still doesn't work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `b` is declared as `binary` so it can only take values 0 or 1. You haven't provided a data file, but the error message suggests that the data for `b` is out of domain (not 0 or 1), for example:

```
data;
set W := w1;
set V := v1;
param b := w1 v1 0.5;
```

AMPL gives a more detailed error message in this case:

```
error processing param b['w1','v1']:
    failed check: param b['w1','v1'] = 0.5
        is not binary (0 or 1);
```

The reason why the order of indices doesn't matter in this case is that the data for `b` is checked completely before the model is actually instantiated. So it seems that `w1` and `v1` may be swapped in the data file.